# Can I define pattern synonyms in OCaml?

Tags: ocaml

Haskell has [`PatternSynonyms`](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/pattern_synonyms.html) which enables to simplify a complex pattern matching. An example is shown in that extension description page. That is, for `Type` below,

```hs
data Type = App String [Type]
```

with these pattern synonyms

```hs
pattern Arrow t1 t2 = App "->"    [t1, t2]
pattern Int         = App "Int"   []
pattern Maybe t     = App "Maybe" [t]
```

we can simplify the pattern matches as follows

```hs
collectArgs :: Type -> [Type]
collectArgs (Arrow t1 t2) = t1 : collectArgs t2
collectArgs _             = []

isInt :: Type -> Bool
isInt Int = True
isInt _   = False

isIntEndo :: Type -> Bool
isIntEndo (Arrow Int Int) = True
isIntEndo _               = False
```

Is it possible to do this kind of pattern match simplification in OCaml?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, patterns synonyms are not available in OCaml (at the time of writing this answer).